# Android margin top negative value in ScrollView

Tags: android, material-design

I had tried to give negative marginTop value to the child inside scrollview.
But it was not aligning as expected. It was hiding below layout which is above the scrollview. I want to achieve the design which i mentioned in Screenshot. Particularly the logo which was floating 75% in banner and 25% below banner. Could anyone give your ideas for that.

I was using android support design library latest.

[image]

Comment: any reason why you are embedding anything in scroll view?

Answer (score 2):

I have just implemented same layout design. 
I would like to share it with you. Hope it will help you.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#FFFFFF">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layoutActionbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/actionbar_background"
        android:orientation="horizontal">


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtBack"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:background="@mipmap/back" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/lblHeader"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="left|center"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:text=""
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/layoutTop"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/layoutActionbar"
        android:background="#F0F0F0"
        android:gravity="center">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtTitle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_above="@+id/txtSubTitle"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:lines="2"
            android:paddingLeft="50dp"
            android:paddingRight="50dp"
            android:text=""
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtSubTitle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:lines="2"
            android:paddingLeft="50dp"
            android:paddingRight="50dp"
            android:text=""
            android:textSize="20sp" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/layoutBottom"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/layoutTop">


        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">


                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="22dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="22dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
                    android:text="ADDITIONAL INFORMATION"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:textColor="#007DCE" />


                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txtDescreiption"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="22dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                    android:text=""
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />


                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="22dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="22dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                    android:text="SOURCES and LINKS"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:textColor="#007DCE" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txtWebsites"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="22dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                    android:autoLink="web"
                    android:text=""
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

            </LinearLayout>
        </ScrollView>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_above="@id/layoutBottom"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="-20dp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:background="#F0F0F0">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/favImage"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_favourite_selected" />
    </LinearLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

How about playing with weights?

```
  <ScrollView

        ...>
        <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:weightSum="1"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          >
        <ImageView
            <!-- android:layout_marginTop="40dp" -->
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.75"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_goeuro_logo"/>
        <ImageView android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.25"
            android:src="@drawable/placeholder_logo"
            />

      </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this affect by using a `RelativeLayout` with a `transparent` background.

The icon at the top is the top element in the layout and the list is below.  In sudo code it might look something like this

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:background="@background/myBannerImage"
    ...>
    <RelativeLayout
        android:marginTop="100dp"
        android:background="@color/transparent"
        ...>
        <ImageView
            android:centerInParent="true"
            android:elevation="15dp"
            .../>
        <LinearLayout
            android:elevation="5dp"
            android:centerInParent="true"
            android:marginTop="25dp" // depends on your image
            android:background="@color/white"
            ...>
            <!-- all the other views -->
        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

If your problem is that one view overlaps the other while it should be the opposite, you can use a `FrameLayout`, where the order of which `View` is on top depends on the order you define your `View`s in the XML layout file. If you have

```
<FrameLayout
 ...>
    <View id="@+id/viewA" ... />
    <View id="@+id/viewB" ... />
</FrameLayout>
```

Then view B will be on top of view A.

Answer (score 0):

`FrameLayout` with `ScrollView` and any other `View`, only ScrollView should respond to `TouchEvent` and Focus the rest of the `View` can be positioned to your preferred location

you can always fall on `FrameLayout.bringChildToFront(View v)` to change the Z-order